# Can we do regular geodesic tiling on a quadric surface, such as hyperboloid and paraboloid?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling, noneuclidean-geometry

Can we do regular tiling on a quadric surface, such as hyperboloid and paraboloid? Assume that the straight lines are the geodesics. Can you show the pictures of the tiling?

Comment: Can you please explain what's meant by _uniform_ in this setting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean regular tiling or tessellation.

Comment: On a surface of constant curvature, _regular_ usually encompasses congruent tiles with equal-length sides and equal interior angles, or at least mutually-congruent tiles. But on a general quadric surface (presumably embedded isometrically in Euclidean three-space)...?

Comment: I have seen some spherical tiling and hyperbolic  tiling, but it's only projection and poincare  disk model. Can we visualize the “real” hyperbolic  plane?

Comment: What is a hyperbolic  plane actually?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something...

Comment: any headway here? Trying to figure out the same thing. Could imagine using a mesher to optimize the triangles to all have the same size/shape.